# After checking session it is not redirecting to another page

Tags: php, session-variables

Here is my code in which i am checking if session variable is not set then it will redirect to another page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779"); 
}
```

**Problem:** It is not redirecting to another page BUT if i change this line

```
header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779");
```

to

```
die("You aren't allowed to access this page");
```

then it works. So Kindly tell me why it is not redirecting to another page?

**EDIT:** This is my whole code of that wordpress page im currently working on:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
 {
 header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779"); 
 exit(); 
 }

 if (isset($_POST["cancel"]))
{
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
 header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779"); 
    exit(); 
  }
 ?>
 <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div align="right">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Log Out" name="cancel" id="cancel" style=""/>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You should add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` at the top of the file.

Comment: Is this at the top of your document? Do you have outputs before it? Perhaps headers are already sent.

Comment: im working on wordpress page, it didn't work.

Comment: I had a similar problem some month (or years) ago. My solution was to put a ob_end_clean(); before the header(). The PHP doc says it should be fine without, but i got working only with ob_end_clean(); before the header()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. If this is just the code it will work fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779"); 
}
```

If you have any other code after this you may get `headers already sent` notice.

**EDIT :**

You can even achieve this using JS. [However , I personally don't recommend]

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    //header("location: http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779");
    echo "<script>document.location.href='http://myweb.com/rel_notes/?page_id=779'</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: yes i do have code but there is no error displayed and didnt work :/
by the way im working on wordpress page.

Comment: Yeah Malik it should. Problem is it will fail when users disable JS on their browser. But however don't worry exit saves you from executing the remaining part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any output above this code? `header("location: ...");` works only if there was no output yet. If you need it nonetheless, add `ob_start();` at the top of your script.